# AWS Java Lambda dependency JAR size management with Maven

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that takes around ~10 seconds to start up using Java-11. I did some googling and came across a number of posts that suggest that lowering the JAR size of the package may help with quicker start times (less redundant libraries loaded etc...).

I also read in some posts that using below may help and tried to add

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

in the AWS related dependencies thinking that well...AWS Lambda would have AWS specific libraries present? Turns out that is not the case! adding scope provided does not work when trying to execute the function.

My current `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>REMOVED</groupId>
    <artifactId>REMOVED</artifactId>
    <version>REMOVED</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>

        </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.228</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency><groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId><artifactId>firehose</artifactId><version>2.17.198</version></dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/kinesis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.201</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/secretsmanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.204</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

AWS Kinesis usage is just to create the KinesisClient and use PutRecordRequest and PutRecordResponse, with AWS Secret Manager , just to access specific secrets.

I am not that versed in AWS API, from my understanding I am already including a limited amount of libraries required to perform those tasks based on the dependencies.

The JAR file is about 65 MB large. Would I be able to optimise dependency loads further? And I guess would lowering the JAR file increase start up time of the Lambda function?

Thank you,

Comment: would using Lambda Layers help?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: Layering has helped quite a lot to reduce JAR size. Lambda execution time is much faster now, the slowness was due to cold starts from the looks of it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/) does not reduce the size of your Lambda (which I am also struggling with), but it helps with cold starts without any code changes.
In their example it changed the start time from about 5 seconds to 2 seconds. It worked for me.

Simply add an lambda environment variable:

```
Key: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Value: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
```

There is also an [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/lambda-optimize-starttime.html) that describes how to remove Netty and Apache clients in favour of the built in JDK client. This reduces the size.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Use the UrlConnectionHttpClient which wraps Java's HTTP client.

```
S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
       .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
       .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
       .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().build())
       .build();
```

Finally you can use [Jackson-jr](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr) which is a +- 100kb version of Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've accidentally included three copies of the same dependency. You just want the latest 2.x.x version of the Kinesis library.

You certainly don't need a 1.x.x SDK and a 2.x.x SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve the issue of cold starts with the new [SnapStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html) feature for AWS lambda written in Java. It basically creates a snapshot of the container used to spin up your java lambda after the initialization/first cold start and saves it. Next time you invoke the lambda it will 'restore' the snapshot which typically takes a few hundred milliseconds rather than start completely cold which takes seconds.

If you are using the AWS CDK then here is an example of how you can configure snapstart on a lambda behind an API gateway. Basically you need to create a new lambda version with alias and apply snapstart to the published versions of your lambda.

```
package com.snapstart.example;

import software.amazon.awscdk.Stack;
import software.amazon.awscdk.StackProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.LambdaIntegration;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.RestApi;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Runtime;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.*;
import software.constructs.Construct;

import java.util.Map;


public class MyStack extends Stack {
    public MyStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);
   

FunctionProps functionProps = FunctionProps.builder().
        handler("com.snapstart.example.MyHandler::handleRequest")
        .code(Code.fromAsset("../software/target/software-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"))
        .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_11).build();

Function function = new Function(this, "lambda-with-snapstart", functionProps);

// configure SnapStart on published versions of this lambda.
((CfnFunction) function.getNode().getDefaultChild())
        .addPropertyOverride("SnapStart", Map.of("ApplyOn", "PublishedVersions"));

// create a new lambda version with alias.
Version lambdaVersion = Version.Builder.create(this, "snapstart-lambda-version")
        .lambda(function).build();

Alias alias = Alias.Builder.create(this, "snapstart-lambda-alias")
        .aliasName("snapstart-alias-name").version(lambdaVersion).build();

// Use the lambda alias when creating the lambda integration rather than the function its self.
LambdaIntegration lambdaIntegration = LambdaIntegration.Builder.create(alias).build();

RestApi api = RestApi.Builder.create(this, "java-with-snapstart-api")
        .description("An API for testing java SnapStart.").build();

api.getRoot().resourceForPath("mypath").addMethod("POST", lambdaIntegration);

}
```